# How can I diagnose my issue deserializing a buffer into a structure?

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I am trying to understand how to dynamically allocate memory for the c-strings in this structure.  Please skip to the output below the code with my explanations.

Here is the code I am running:

```
 NN #define USAGE "[get|put|quit] filenamesource filenamedest"
...
 20 enum cmd_type get_type(char *cmd) {
 21     if (0 == strncmp("put", cmd, 3)) {
 22         return PUT;
 23     }
 24     else if (0 == strncmp("get", cmd, 3)) {
 25         return GET;
 26     }
 27     else if (0 == strncmp("quit", cmd, 3)) {
 28         return QUIT;
 29     }
 30     else {
 31         return INV;
 32     }
 33 }
...
  0 int _recv_cmd(char *cmd_buf) {
 34     char type[MAX_FILENAME_LEN] = { '\0' };
 33     char src[MAX_FILENAME_LEN] = { '\0' };
 32     char dest[MAX_FILENAME_LEN] = { '\0' };
 31     size_t size = 0;
 30     enum error err = 0;
 29     struct command *cmd = NULL;
 28
 27     printf("Process %d received serialized command '%s'\n", getpid(), cmd_buf);
 26
 25     cmd = malloc(sizeof cmd);
 24     if (NULL == cmd) {
 23         perror("malloc");
 22         return -1;
 21     }
 20     if (5 != sscanf(cmd_buf, " %s %s %s %zu %u ", type, src, dest, &size, &err)) {
 19         fprintf(stderr, "sscanf failed to scan input.\n");
 18         free(cmd);
 17         return -1;
 16     }
 15
 14     printf("%s, %s, %s, %zu, %u\n", type, src, dest, size, err);
 13
 12     cmd->type = get_type(type);
 11     cmd->src = strdup(src);
 10     cmd->dest = strdup(dest);
  9     cmd->fsz = size;
  8     cmd->err = err;
  7
  6     print_cmd(cmd);
  5
  4     free(cmd);
  3
  2     return 0;
  1 }
...
  0 char * _get_input(char *buf) {
  1     // get input
  2     if (NULL == fgets(buf, CMD_LIMIT, stdin)) {
  3         fprintf(stderr, "fgets failed.\n");
  4         return NULL;
  5     }
  6     // remove newline
  7     int newline_pos = strcspn(buf, "\n");
  8     buf[newline_pos] = '\0';
  9
 10     return buf;
 11 }
 12
 13 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
 14     char cmd_buf[CMD_LIMIT] = { '\0' };
 15
 16     while(1) {
 17
 18         printf("Enter command of the form '%s':\n", USAGE);
 19
 20         _recv_cmd(_get_input(cmd_buf));
 21     }
 22
 23     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
 24 }
```

Here is the command type:

```
 29 struct command {
 30     enum cmd_type type;
 31     char *src;
 32     char *dest;
 33     size_t fsz;
 34     enum error err;
 35 };
```

This is the output I get from running the programming.  Notice the spaces I add between examples.

```
➜  assignment01 git:(master) ✗ ./test
Enter command of the form '[get|put|quit] filenamesource filenamedest':
put hi hi 25 0
Process 53001 received serialized command 'put hi hi 25 0'
put, hi, hi, 25, 0
type: 2, source:  , dest: , size: 25, err: 0
Enter command of the form '[get|put|quit] filenamesource filenamedest':
put  hi hi 25 0
Process 53022 received serialized command 'put  hi hi 25 0'
put, hi, hi, 25, 0
type: 2, source: 'p, dest: , size: 25, err: 0
Enter command of the form '[get|put|quit] filenamesource filenamedest':
get  what is 30 1
Process 53022 received serialized command 'get  what is 30 1'
get, what, is, 30, 1
type: 1, source: what, dest: is, size: 30, err: 1
```

As can be seen in the output, the buffer contents look exactly as I would expect them to look ("received serialized...").  Nothing unusual there.

The output on the lines directly below that of the prompt are from the line

`printf("%s, %s, %s, %zu, %u\n", type, src, dest, size, err);`,

indicating that sscanf has worked exactly as I expected.  Why, then, are the contents of cmd so messed up?

I understand that room for the pointer to the strings `src` and `dest` are given with the malloc for `cmd`, and that strdup is malloc'ing room for (null character and everything) for the c-strings in the struct itself.  What gives?

I already tried alternate methods such as malloc'ing and then strncpy or memmove.

I will just add that these leading underscores are chosen so function names don't conflict with those in common.h.  This is a minumum working example used to recreate the problem - not the original code I was working with.  The same applies to not freeing the strings, etc.  Just overlooked when building this small test application.

`print_cmd` simply printf's the struct with the appropriate formatting, exactly as one would imagine.

Comment: Where's `print_cmd`?

Comment: unrelated, but it doesn't appear like you ever free the `strdup`d strings, so that's leaking memory

Comment: Also, note that you're accepting pretty much any old integer into your `enum error` without cleaning it up.

Comment: `cmd = malloc(sizeof cmd);` allocs only 8 bytes. Use `cmd = malloc (sizeof *cmd)`

Comment: don't use leading underscores for identifiers

Comment: @NickODell has the right answer.  You aren't allocating enough memory for `cmd`, so you are writing to unowned memory when you set cmd->src, etc.

Comment: @NickODell I would like to accept your answer but don't know how!  There is no checkmark to click next to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
cmd = malloc(sizeof cmd);
```

Allocates enough space for a pointer to a structure, but you want enough space for the structure itself. You can solve this with

```
cmd = malloc(sizeof *cmd);
```

or

```
cmd = malloc(sizeof(struct command));
```